# Stack of Images as Single Input to CNN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am newbie, I need your help. How can I combine 3 different images for making single input for CNN neural network? In simple words I am using list of 3 images as single input with one output.

let's suppose :

```
x1=[img1,img2,img3] ====> y1
x2=[img1,img2,img3] ====> y2
x3=[img1,img2,img3] ====> y3
```

Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is that it's pretty trivial. The actual way of doing it depends on the framework that you're using. So the answer will be different depending on whether you're using Keras/PyTorch/Tensorflow

Comment: thanks for comment, actually i am using keras/tensorflow.

Answer (score 3):

The idea in this case is is known as a multi-input model. Such model would have a stack of layer until some point where every stack is concatenated to follow a new stack of prediction. You can imagine it as this:

[image: Multi-input model]

The source of this image and the implementation of such model can be found here: https://blog.csdn.net/alphachx/article/details/96482328